# php : Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property

Tags: php, class, parent-child, parent, extends

good morning

the first this is the code

loader.php

```
class loader{
  public $main_c;
  function __construct(){
    $this->main_c['one']=array("a","b","c");
    $this->main_c['two']=array("e","f","g");
    $this->loadtwo();
  }
  function loadtwo(){
   require_once(home.php);
   $browser=new browser();
   $browser->add();
  }
}
 $loader=new loader();
```

home.php

```
class browser extends loader{

function __construct(){ 
   print $this->main_c;    //empty value
}

function add(){
        print parent::$main_c //Fatal error: Access to undeclared static     property: loader::$main_c
         print parent::main_c; //Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'main_c'
       }
    }
```

infact i need to add or change in main_c

from file browser.php

Comment: Looks like you're confusing classes and instances

Comment: You are also treating `main_c` as an array in the constructor. You have to set it to be an array before using it as one.

Comment: i make public $main_c=array(); but no thing happen..... and i removed it and too no thing happen